# Which sentence is more grammatically correct as well as sounds more natural using the verb "to reminisce"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-order

I'm writing about my project and want to explain how the location looked like years ago when the city used to be more green. Now I am not sure which of the below sentences is more grammatically correct, or sounds more natural in terms of word order and using the figures of speech?

If none is good, how can I use word "to reminisce" in my sentence? I like this word a lot and want to use it!

*Version 1- Today just a few of those orchards, the magnificent past that one would reminiscing about, have remained and it will not take very long before these doomed survivors will also be turned into towers.*

*Version 2- Today just a few of those orchards which remind us the magnificent past have remained, and it will not take very long before these doomed survivors will also be turned into towers.*

To me, the first sentence sounds deeper, and more literary but I'm not sure how it sounds to a native speaker?

Comment: "Reminisce the past" is not good English.

Comment: We don't proofread here. Please edit your question and identify specific places in your sentences you are uncertain about and tell us why you think they may be incorrect.

Comment: Many thanks! I edited my question after getting the first comment from Michael and also changed the question as you've mentioned Eddie. BM

Comment: _To reminisce_ doesn't mean the same as _to remember_, it means to think or talk about how things used to be - and you can't say _one would reminiscing_.